# Is this a matter of using 'partition by' correctly?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, analytics

I want to use analytics for this because I have several other similair statistics I'd like 
report.

**Q:**  Using Oracle Analytics, how can I get just one row per airport?

```
with detail_records as 
(select 1 as passenger_id, 'ATL' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 10  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 2 as passenger_id, 'ATL' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 25  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 2 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 20  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 3 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 30  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 4 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 40  as luggage_weight  from dual
 )
 select  airport,
         count(*) over (partition by airport) as airport_count,
         sum(luggage_weight) over (partition by airport, gate) as a_g_weight
 from detail_records
 where gate='E4'
```

**Results**

```
AIRPORT  AIRPORT_COUNT   A_G_WEIGHT
ATL      2              35
ATL      2              35
SFO      3              90
SFO      3              90
SFO      3              90
```

**Desired Results**

```
 Airport  Airport_count   A_G_WEIGHT
 ATL       2              35
 SFO       3              90
```

Comment: Try `select DISTINCT airport, ...`

Comment: If you filter by a single gate the partition by that column isn't adding anything; if you filter by multiple gates (or all) then you'll have multiple `a_g_weight` values without anything to explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wernfried said, your looking for the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Since the "passenger ID" column doesn't matter, and want to avoid duplicates, you must call it so:

```
with detail_records as 
(select 1 as passenger_id, 'ATL' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 10  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 2 as passenger_id, 'ATL' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 25  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 2 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 20  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 3 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 30  as luggage_weight  from dual union all
 select 4 as passenger_id, 'SFO' as airport, 'E4' as gate, 40  as luggage_weight  from dual
 )
 select  distinct airport,
         count(*) over (partition by airport) as airport_count,
         sum(luggage_weight) over (partition by airport, gate) as a_g_weight
 from detail_records
 where gate='E4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple GROUP BY query

```
select  airport,
        count(*) as airport_count,
        sum(luggage_weight) as a_g_weight
from detail_records
where gate='E4'
group by airport
```